# Is there way to parse JSON like this from MySQL

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I want to create a PHP API from server to parse JSON to Android
but never mind of that.

The main problem is how can I code this

This is my PHP code

```
<?php

include 'includes/conn.php';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY priority ASC";

$res = array();

        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

            $csql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE position_id='".$row['id']."'";
            $cquery = $conn->query($csql);

            $cs = array( 
              'pos_id' => $row['id'],
                'pos_des' => $row['description'],
                'max_votes' => $row['max_vote']);

            while($crow = $cquery->fetch_assoc()){

                    $fe = array(
                      'candidates' => array(
                     'id' => $crow['id'],
                     'pos_id' => $crow['position_id'],
                     'firstname' => $crow['firstname'],
                     'lastname' => $crow['lastname'],
                     'photo' => $crow['photo'],
                     'platform' => $crow['platform']

                     array_push($cs,fe);

                 )          
            );

        }

        array_push($res,$cs);

}

    echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

Now its working fine but instead
of this

```
 [{
        "pos_id": "1",
        "pos_des": "Reprisentative",
        "max_votes": "4",
        "candidates": {
            "id": "1",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "G-9-JAY",
            "lastname": "MCARTHUR",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "pos_id": "1",
        "pos_des": "Reprisentative",
        "max_votes": "4",
        "candidates": {
            "id": "2",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "G-10-JOHN",
            "lastname": "MARTIN",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "pos_id": "1",
        "pos_des": "Reprisentative",
        "max_votes": "4",
        "candidates": {
            "id": "5",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "GRADE 7",
            "lastname": "Lang ya",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "pos_id": "2",
        "pos_des": "President",
        "max_votes": "1",
        "candidates": {
            "id": "3",
            "pos_id": "2",
            "firstname": "User",
            "lastname": "Name",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "pos_id": "2",
        "pos_des": "President",
        "max_votes": "1",
        "candidates": {
            "id": "4",
            "pos_id": "2",
            "firstname": "TEST",
            "lastname": "USER",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }
    }
 ]
```

I want this result

```
  [{
        "pos_id": "1",
        "pos_des": "Reprisentative",
        "max_votes": "4",
        "candidates": [{
            "id": "1",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "G-9-JAY",
            "lastname": "MCARTHUR",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "G-10-JOHN",
            "lastname": "MARTIN",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }, {
            "id": "5",
            "pos_id": "1",
            "firstname": "GRADE 7",
            "lastname": "Lang ya",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }]

    },
    {
        "pos_id": "2",
        "pos_des": "President",
        "max_votes": "1",
        "candidates": [{
            "id": "3",
            "pos_id": "2",
            "firstname": "User",
            "lastname": "Name",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "pos_id": "2",
            "firstname": "TEST",
            "lastname": "USER",
            "photo": "",
            "platform": ""
        }]
    }
  ]
```

Summary: I want The user to place in what pos_id he/she assign to the positions for example MARTIN is a running in president so MARTIN should show in President Position

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should push onto `$cs['candidates']`, not create a separate array with `candidates` as the key for each candidate.

```
            $cs = array( 
                'pos_id' => $row['id'],
                'pos_des' => $row['description'],
                'max_votes' => $row['max_vote'],
                'candidates' => array());

            while($crow = $cquery->fetch_assoc()){
                $cs['candidates'][] = array(
                    'id' => $crow['id'],
                    'pos_id' => $crow['position_id'],
                    'firstname' => $crow['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $crow['lastname'],
                    'photo' => $crow['photo'],
                    'platform' => $crow['platform']
                );
            }
```

Comment: .     error: syntax error, unexpected ''candidates''         (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in line 23

Comment: I was missing a comma.